# How do you pass in a password to a Node application started with Forever?

Tags: node.js, bash, forever

I want to run a Node application using Forever, but I can't figure out how to pass in a password as an argument without it being visible in the Node list (and even the bash history!).  I had set up the Prompt module so that when the Node app starts I can enter the password (and it's not visible in the console), but when I start the app with Forever, it's not run in the foreground, so I never get the prompt.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The easy ( though possibly undesirable) way is you could save the password to desk in a text file( password.txt) and tell node to check if that exists before prompting for the password. You would then only include that file if you were deploying on a site using forever (i.e. ec2 or heroku)

Answer (score 0):

you can unset the HISTFILE environment variable for the current session, thus nothing is logged to ~/.bash_history.

```
$ unset HISTFILE
```

Best
Marc